# Passing members of an instance from one windows form to another

Tags: c#, winforms, list, combobox, instance

I have a main windows form (MainForm.cs) where I created an instance of Customer cust.

Here is a snippet of said code:

```
private Customer cust;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void buttonDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DepositDialog dlg = new DepositDialog();

    dlg.ShowDialog();
}
```

Here is the code for the Customer class. As you can see, it creates a list of BankAccounts:

```
class Customer
{
    private BankAccountCollection accounts;

    public Customer(BankAccountCollection accounts, TransactionCollection transactionHistory)
    {
        accounts.Add(new SavingsAccount(true,200));
        accounts.Add(new SavingsAccount(true, 1000));
        accounts.Add(new LineOfCreditAccount(true, 0));
    }

    public BankAccountCollection Accounts
    { get { return accounts; }}
}
```

Now, I have another form called DepositDialog, which has a comboBox within it.

How would I:

1) pass the data **BankAccountCollection accounts**

2) populate that comboBox with the members of that BankAccountCollection

3) display that collection as items within the list?

Comment: If you already have the data and you wish to just populate it when you launch a dialog, then do as pranay says. If on dynamic i.e on some events then use Events and Delegates

Comment: I think you may have a problem in your `Customer` constructor. You have `accounts` as a private member and also as a parameter. You have to know that you are adding the new objects to the parameter rather than the private member.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Comment: Thank you Mun Pieng. I've changed it to be a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) pass the data BankAccountCollection accounts

There's actually **5 ways** to pass the data.

1- (Not recommended if there's too many parameters) Passing data through the constructor.

```
 private void ShowForm(int a, string b, double c)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2(a, b, c);
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

2- Using public fields of target class. (NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL)

```
 private void ShowForm(int a, string b, double c)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.intval = a;
    frm.strval = b;
    frm.doubleval = c;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

3- Using properties.

```
 private void ShowForm(int a, string b, double c)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.IntValue = a;
    frm.StringValue = b;
    frm.DoubleValue = c;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

4- Using tags.

```
private void ShowForm(int a, string b, double c)
{
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.SomeTextBox.Tag = a;
        frm.SomeTextBox2.Tag = b;
        frm.SomeTextBox3.Tag = c;
        frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

5- Using delegates. (This one is a little bit tricky).

```
 //in Form2
public delegate void PassValues(int a, string b, double c);
public PassValues passVals;

private void PassDataThroughDelegate(int a, string b, double c)
{
    if(passVals != null)
        passVals(a,b,c);
}

//in Form1
private void ShowForm(int a, string b, double c)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.passVals = new Form2.PassValues(UseData);
    frm.ShowDialog();
}

private void UseData(int a, string b, double c)
{
}
```

My personal favorite ones are the properties, delegates and in some rare cases constructors.

Alternatively, you can create a static class , put some properties in it, then use it in other forms.
 This is really helpful if all of your forms need to share some information. Since this is not a way to Pass data between the forms, I did not mention this method in those above.

> 2) populate that comboBox with the members of that
>   BankAccountCollection

Once you passed the data between forms, using it for population is not hard.

```
foreach(BankAccount acc in accounts)
   combobox1.Items.Add(acc.ToString());
```

> 3) display that collection as items within the list?

You can use event handler for combobox1 to do whatever you want with the selected item.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You just make use of parameterise constructor ans pass the Collection as argument may do the task for you

```
private void buttonDeposit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
   DepositDialog dlg = new DepositDialog(cust.accounts);      
   dlg.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

Check this for passing argument : [C# Using New Windows Form Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using-new-windows-form)

Comment: How would I overload the constructor so that it takes a collection? What is the code signature?

Comment: @iggy2012: The same as your existing `Customer` signature - just with different parameters, and the same name as the class you're creating the constructor for...

Comment: Something like `DepositDialog(BankAccountCollection collection)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few other ones...

My favorite - Make a custom 'Initialize()' function to set the data, and then open the form normally using ShowDialog().  Then you can have many forms implement the interface, and show them dynamically.

```
private Customer Customer { get ; set; }
public void Initialize(Customer cust) {
    this.Customer = cust;
}


var f = new CustomerForm();
f.Initialize(_myCustomer);
f.ShowDialog();
```

You can override the ShowDialog() function, but that leaves you with three overrides now, which may or may not be acceptable.  Also override the one with the `owner` property if you need it.

```
public void ShowDialog(Customer cust) {
     this.Customer = cust;
     base.ShowDialog();
}
```

You can hide the old ShowDialog() to prevent people from calling it.  This can be escaped by simply casting the type as `Form`, so it's not really a solution.

```
new public void ShowDialog() { 
     throw new Exception("arg!");
}

(new CustomerForm()).ShowDialog();  // exception!
(new CustomerForm() as Form).ShowDialog()  // works fine
```